# Wordpress - 'Read more' not showing with get_page

Tags: wordpress

I'm sure I'm missing some code here;

```
<?php
    $id = 38;
    $p = get_page($id);
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content);
?>
```

I checked a post here on Stackoverflow and they said I should change post_content to post_excerpt. However when I do that my content disappears.

I'd like to use the read more insert button from the WP UI.

Perhaps I need to change the code a bit or add something to functions.php?

Anyway thanks in advance for any replies.

-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) function has been deprecated, use standard [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). "Read More" tag [does not work](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#How_to_use_Read_More_in_Pages) in "Pages", it must be manually enabled, and it must be inside the loop. There is another benefit of the loop that it sets up global post data so that you can freely use [Template Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) in the current post context.

```
<?php 
    $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=page&p=38' );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        global $more; $more = 0;            
        the_content();
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Great, that works, just wondering though, can you change the text of the read more?  For example to 'Read more..' instead of '(more..)'?

Comment: @Rudolf, just use `the_content( 'Read more ...' );`, check out the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content). If this answer helped, consider to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)